# Jquery Airport runs indefinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout

I'm using Jquery Airport in the following way:

```
$('#basketTotal').airport([s]);
$('#basketTotal').html(s);
```

Here's the Airport function:

```
(function($){ 
    $.fn.extend({  
        airport: function(array) {
        var self = $(this);
        var chars = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','.','£'];
        var longest = 0;
        var items = items2 = array.length;
        function pad(a,b) { return a + new Array(b - a.length + 1).join(' '); }
        $(this).empty();
        while(items--)
            if(array[items].length > longest) longest = array[items].length;
        while(items2--)
            array[items2] = pad(array[items2],longest);
        spans = longest;
        while(spans--) {
            $(this).prepend("<span class='c" + spans + "'></span>");
        }

            function testChar(a,b,c,d){
            $(self).find('.c'+a).html((chars[b]==" ")?"&nbsp;":chars[b]);
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(b > chars.length)
                    testChar(a+1,0,c,d+1);
                else if(chars[b] != array[c].substring(d,d+1).toLowerCase())
                    testChar(a,b+1,c,d);
                else
                    testChar(a+1,0,c,d+1);
            }, 15);


        }
        testChar(0,0,0,0);
    } 

    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

I'm only ever going to pass one string to the airport function (not an array of strings).  Airport runs indefinitely and doesn't stop, but I need to make it stop and perform `$('#basketTotal').html(s);` when it's finished.

How can I make the function stop when it's finished one iteration of the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of `testChar()`, you can add a test to see if you're done with the number of iterations you want to do and if so, just return.

If you return from `testChar()` without doing a `setTimeout()`, then the animation will stop.

I don't quite understand when you want it to stop so I'm not sure exactly what test condition to recommend, but it would go here:

```
       function testChar(a,b,c,d){

           // if (done now) return;

           $(self).find('.c'+a).html((chars[b]==" ")?"&nbsp;":chars[b]);
           setTimeout(function() {
               if(b > chars.length)
                   testChar(a+1,0,c,d+1);
               else if(chars[b] != array[c].substring(d,d+1).toLowerCase())
                   testChar(a,b+1,c,d);
               else
                   testChar(a+1,0,c,d+1);
           }, 15);
        }
```

If it's just a simple counter for a specific number of iterations, then you can just initialize that counter before `testChar(), increment it inside of`testChar()` and check to see if the desired number of iterations have been completed.  If so, just return without setting the timer.

OK, after studying your code a bit (that is one obscure algorithm without any description of how it's supposed to work), it looks like you can terminate the animation like this:

```
    function testChar(a,b,c,d){
        // if we're beyond the number of spans we have, we must be done
        if (a > longest) return;

        $(self).find('.c'+a).html((chars[b]==" ")?"&nbsp;":chars[b]);
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(b > chars.length)
                testChar(a+1,0,c,d+1);
            else if(chars[b] != array[c].substring(d,d+1).toLowerCase())
                testChar(a,b+1,c,d);
            else
                testChar(a+1,0,c,d+1);
        }, 15);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  Knowing how many iterations to stop at is extremely difficult.  Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3rPJ4/1/

It should stop after it's updated it to £9.99 if that makes more sense!  I only want it to run through the animation once, then stop.

Comment: I added one way to terminate the loop.  Without more description of what your algorithm does, I don't know if this is the earliest you can terminate the loop, but it does stop it when you've now looking for more spans than you have.

Comment: Awesome thanks, works great!  I agree the function is obscure, it's a small one I found here: http://unwrongest.com/projects/airport/